# How to iterate over different ids levels using weakref in kivy

Tags: python, object, iteration, kivy, weak-references

I have this sequence of **ids**.

`self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.ids.pre_1.ids.Si`

In this case, **container** has 70 different ids [from *pre_1* until *pre_70*] and each pre_(x) has three different ids [*Si*, *MasMenos*, *No*] that correspondes to a group of **CheckBoxes**.

If I want to know the state of a single checkbox using its atribute **value**, I'm forced to write all the statement like this.

`self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.ids.pre_1.ids.Si.value`.

**So, How can I iterate over the ids?**

I've tried using square brackets `self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.ids['pre_1']` but it returns something with which I can't call any method.

Print with Square brackets: `<weakref at 0x125F7118; to 'BoxLayout' at 0x125F30D0>`

Print with dot notation: `<kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x125F30D0>`

This is the way I've created the objects:

```
for idx in range(70):

  BoxContainer = BoxLayout()

  # Repeat this two more times with MasMenos and No

  check1 = CheckBox(group= f"p_{idx+1}")
  BoxContainer.add_widget(check1)
  BoxContainer.ids['Si'] = weakref.ref(check1)


  #Adding the BoxContainer with CheckBoxes to the container

  self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.add_widget(BoxContainer)
  self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.ids[f'pre_{idx+1}'] = weakref.ref(BoxContainer)
```

Comment: Why not just *not* do this? You're making the objects and adding them to the ids dict yourself, so you could instead iterate through them some other way if you'd prefer.

Comment: This is the only way in which I was able to make it work, How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use **weakref**, every time that `add_widget` is used, an **Observable List** called **children** into the object in which was added the other one will contain the reference of that added object.

For example:

```
IDlist = self.ids.cuarta_pantalla.ids.container.children
```

The variable **IDlist** can be iterated to get each reference where you can call any method of that particular object